# Get latest on checkout is not supported in local workspaces. Checking out the local version

Tags: tfs

I keep getting the message **Get latest on checkout is not supported in local workspaces. Checking out the local version** every time I do anything such as move or add controls to a frm. I wasn't getting this message till I did a check in of some code. This appears in the Output window and it's constantly happening. 
I searched the web for this message with no luck. I didn't do any kind of check out as I knew that would happen as soon as I made any changes but I didn't expect this and I'm afraid of what might happen if I ignore it and lose all my work.
Can anyone help? I'm using VS 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue on local workspace when enable get latest on check-out option.

**Enable get latest on check-out option** is only available for **Server workspace** (Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace#when-might-i-need-to-use-a-server-workspace) for details.). If you are using local workspace and enabled the get latest on check-out option, then the message "`Get latest on checkout is not supported in local workspaces. Checking out the local version`" will appear when you edit files.

However, you can ignore the message, the message just indicated that it checked out the local version but not the latest server version. You can **Get Latest Version** (right-click --> Get Latest Version) first if you want to check out the latest server version.

So, the problem on local workspace is caused by enabled the source control option: **Get latest version of item on check-out in a server workspace**. If you don't want to output the message, you can **uncheck** the option. (Tools -> Options... -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server)

[image]

Comment: That appears to be the issue. Thanks much!

Comment: The reason I checked that in Tools -> Options was because I wanted people to automatically get the latest version every time they checked out a project. Am I right in saying that developers still have to explicitly do this when checking out projects?